# React component not updating or remounting when prop changes

Tags: reactjs

I have a component which takes an Id prop and uses it to make some fetch calls to populate itself etc. This id can change or be null and so the component should be able to refetch and do whatever it needs when it has any of these values. When the component is first rendered, the id is always null, but if/when it changes, the components constructor or `componentDidMount()` function are never recalled, and when I tried changing it to `componentDidUpdate()` and manually checking when the value changed, it never even called that with the new id either.

I have the following outer class (heavily simplified) which calls the `EligibilityCard` component and passes the id:

```
class ActionsTab extends React.Component{
    render(){
        let playerId = null;
        if(this.props.data && this.props.data.playerId){
            let playerId = this.props.data.playerId;
        }
        return(
            <EligibilityCard playerId={playerId}/>
        )
    }
}
```

And the component itself (also simplified):

```
class EligibilityCard extends React.Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        const requestData = {event: this.props.event.id};
        if(this.props.playerId){
            requestData.playerId = this.props.playerId;
        }
        $.ajax(path and requestData){
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: In response to some of the comments, I tried changing the `EligibilityCard.componentDidMount()` to this and it only ever printed `null`:

```
class EligibilityCard extends React.Component{
    componentDidUpdate(){
        console.log(this.props.playerId);
```

Using the chrome debugger with breakpoints on the `return` line of `ActionsTab.render()` and the first line of `componentDidMount/Update`: render is called multiple times, initially with `playerId=null` and then eventually with `playerId=somenumber`. The `componentDidMount` breakpoint is reached a few times with `props.playerId=null` as the various elements of the page loads and the screen rerenders, but by the time the id changes in the render function `componentDidUpdate` is not called anymore whatsoever

Comment: That's how it is supposed to work. Props changing do not remount the component, only re-renders.

Comment: @BrianThompson is correct. With class components you can use `componentDidUpdate` to run logic after rerenders.

Comment: As I said in the question itself, I tried `componentDidUpdate` and it was never called with the new id.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what class has the `componentDidUpdate()` method. And show how `playerId` changes.

Comment: Yeah we would need to see a larger context. Whatever is rendering `ActionsTab` may not be doing it correctly. The reason that's important is cuz `ActionTab` does get `this.props.data.playerId` from the parent and thus the successful passage of that prop also matters here. Any chance you can put together a basic reproducible example in CodeSandbox.io?

Comment: You need to use `playerId` as a state variable in ActionsTab, not as a normal variable.

Comment: So we were all wrong! It was just a big ol goof I believe. If you check the first code section, you can see that I reuse the `let` keyword when I reasign playerId inside the if block. This encapsulated the changed version of the variable to within that if blocks scope only. The version outside the if was still always the null version

Answer (score 0):

I reused the `let` keyword when I assigned the int value, restricting the updated value to the scope of the if statement and conserving the null value outside of the if. It should just be:

```
class ActionsTab extends React.Component{
    render(){
        let playerId = null;
        if(this.props.data && this.props.data.playerId){
            playerId = this.props.data.playerId;
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems like the issue might be related to the fact that you're not updating the component's state when the `playerId` prop changes. To fix this, you should move the AJAX call to a separate function and call this function both in `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` when the `playerId` prop changes.

Here's an example of how to achieve this:

```js
class EligibilityCard extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            playerId: null,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchData();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (prevProps.playerId !== this.props.playerId) {
            this.fetchData();
        }
    }

    fetchData() {
        if (this.props.playerId !== this.state.playerId) {
            const requestData = { event: this.props.event.id };
            if (this.props.playerId) {
                requestData.playerId = this.props.playerId;
            }
            $.ajax(/* path and requestData */).then(() => {
                this.setState({ playerId: this.props.playerId });
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        // Render component
    }
}
```

In this example, I've moved the AJAX call to a separate function called `fetchData`. This function checks if the current `playerId` prop is different from the one stored in the state. If it is, it makes the AJAX call and updates the state with the new `playerId` prop.

Now, both `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` will call `fetchData`, which will make the AJAX call whenever the `playerId` prop changes. This should help to ensure that the component updates correctly when the `playerId` prop changes.